# Multiple boolean values in an struct

Tags: c++, struct, enums, dword

I have a question about using multiple boolean values in a struct.

I have an struct

```
typedef struct Foo
{
 foo2,
 foo3
}
```

which is a part of another main struct

```
typedef struct MainFoo
{
  int n,
  ....
  .
  .
  FOO foo
```

and function

```
void foo(int foo)
{
   if(foo)
   b = true;
}
```

and in another function :

```
if(b)
{
 bool Foo.foo2 = true;
}

if(b)
{
  bool Foo.foo3 = true;
}
```

and finally  in the another class I check

```
if(Foo.foo2)
{
  //Do something
}

if(Foo.foo3)
{
 //Do Something
}
```

So My question is if there is any other better way to check these. I tried using Dword but not sure if I understood it but it just got the last boolean state that was checked and hence couldn't check for each boolean one at a time in another class. Any suggestion in this? Is using the struct just for the bool a good practice? If not is there any other better way?

Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps you could post a code example in C++?

Comment: maybe you should use bit fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mainly depends on your problem. Briefly, use the `Foo` struct only if it has some meaning outside `MainFoo` as a whole (for example, if they are all settings that should be transferred all together or saved to a file externally), otherwise move `foo2` and `foo3` to `MainFoo`.

Except for that, the use is correct. On the other hand, you can reduce memory consumption if you use [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

```
struct Foo {
  bool foo2 : 1;
  bool foo3 : 1;
};
```

Comment: PS: you may wish to take a look at the difference between `typedef struct` and `struct` [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/1485885).